# android studio find by id, where id is a variable passed as a parameter

Tags: android, resources

I have hundreds of buttons, all with the same listener and action, but different names. Here is one with the name goes1:

```
public void goes1(){
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.goes1);
    play_text_view = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.goes1);
    play_text_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                lireXML("goes1");
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to have only one method where the name of the button would be passed to the method as a parameter. Something like this, with the String parameter mot:

```
public void playMot(String mot){
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mot);
    play_text_view = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mot);
    play_text_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                lireXML(mot);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

but `R.raw.mot` and `R.id.mot` don't like this!
Should I really have hundreds of buttons, or is there a way around my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Resources.getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).  It looks up a resource id from a string name and type.

```
public void playMot(String mot) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    // Should error check this, returns 0 on error.
    final rawId = res.getIdentifier(mot, "raw", getPackageName());  
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawId);
    // Should error check this, returns 0 on error.
    final resId = res.getIdentifier(mot, "id", getPackageName());  
    play_text_view = (TextView) this.findViewById(resId);
    ...
```

Comment: I followed your advice, and did the same with R.raw.mot. Works wonderful!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can story the relation between name and raw id,the relation between name and view id,in hashMap,like this:

```
        HashMap<String, Long> nameToRawId = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        HashMap<String, Long> nameToViewId = new HashMap<String, Long>();
```

then get id from that hashMap int method playMot(String mot):

```
public void playMot(String mot){
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, nameToRawId.get(mot));
play_text_view = (TextView) this.findViewById(nameToViewId.get(mot));
play_text_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            lireXML(mot);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
    }
});
}
```

hope this can help you.

Comment: Unfortunately the compilation stumbled on get(mot), and I was not able to fix it. lagreen solution, however, works perfectly. Thanks